# The Android Download Manager api failed to download ("Unsuccessful download")

Tags: android, android-download-manager

In some occasions, when trying to download a file with the Android `DownloadManager`, the download failed and the download notification shows "Unsuccessful download".

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of debugging, I realized some of the headers that I was passing to the download manager were `null or empty`. Especially the "User-Agent", when that happens  the download manager posts a notification saying "Unsuccessful download".

```
    val androidDownloadManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as AndroidDownloadManager

    val request = Request(Uri.parse(download.url))
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", download.userAgent)

   androidDownloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: Thank you Arturo, for me I was using "UserAgent" instead "User-Agent" lol

Comment: Happy to help :)